# How to change the body content of an HttpWebRequest object after the GetRequestStream has been written to?

Tags: .net, python, soap, httpwebrequest, ironpython

How to change the body content of an HttpWebRequest object after the GetRequestStream has been written to? It seems that the GetRequestStream is writeonly.

I have an assembly (to which i dont have the source) which creates a HttpWebRequest object and passes it to a python script (iron python) to be modified. The request contains a SOAP envelope as its a web service request. I need to parse and modify some content in this SOAP envelope via the python script as I can edit the script and not the assembly.

Comment: did you find a solution ? I am looking for a similar solution.

Comment: Its not possible sorry to say :(